# How to break line in table cell when found space?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, html-table, href, newline

I would like to new line to each `<a>` in `<td>` by not using `<br>`.

> *Show the result of row 1 exactly the same as row 2 without using `<br>`*

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
  table > tbody > tr > td > a {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Link</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1.</td>
      <td>
        <a>Link 1</a>
        <a>Link 2</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2.</td>
      <td>
        <a>Link 1</a>
        <br>
        <a>Link 2</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `table > tbody > td > a { display: block; }`.

Comment: BTW, your `<th>` elements need `scope` attributes.

Comment: Already add in a question, It's not working.

Comment: I typo'd. You want `table > tbody > tr > td > a { display: block; }`. (I missed the `tr`).